# how to hide a marker or content parts if no content in typo3

Tags: typo3, marker, typoscript

i got a template with a marker ###whatever### its set as TEXT and filled with .value
i need to hide or empty the marker **IF** one of the columns are **empty** (in my case **the normal column colPos=0**)

Comment: Well you can simply set the marker to an empty value to hide it. Are you saying that all 3 conditions should be met? How is the marker defined in the Typoscript template?

Comment: i will edit the question to be more sure what i need...

Comment: If **any** of the 3 columns is empty or if the column 0 is empty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a condition preventing the display of the marker's data if there's no content in the normal (colPos=0) column.

```
YOUR_MARKER = TEXT
YOUR_MARKER {
  # ...your definitions...

  # Check whether there's any content in the column 0
  if.isTrue.cObject = CONTENT
  if.isTrue.cObject {
    table = tt_content
    select {
      where = colPos=0
    }    
    renderObj < tt_content
  }
}
```

YOUR_MARKER obviously has to be the correct path, e.g. page.10.subparts.YOUR_MARKER.